# Using python argparse arguments as variable values within a json file

Tags: json, python-3.x, argparse

I've googled this quite a bit and am unable to find helpful insight. Basically, I need to take the user input from my argparse arguments from a python script (as shown below) and plug those values into a json file (packerfile.json) located in the same working directory. I have been experimenting with `subprocess`, `invoke` and `plumbum` libraries without being able to "find the shoe that fits".

From the following code, I have removed all except for the arguments as to clean up:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os, sys, subprocess
import argparse
import json
from invoke import run
import packer

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser._positionals.title = 'Positional arguments'
parser._optionals.title = 'Optional arguments'
parser.add_argument("--access_key",
                     required=False,
                     action='store',
                     default=os.environ['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
                     help="AWS access key id")
parser.add_argument("--secret_key",
                     required=False,
                     action='store',
                     default=os.environ['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'],
                     help="AWS secret access key")
parser.add_argument("--region",
                     required=False,
                     action='store',
                     help="AWS region")
parser.add_argument("--guest_os_type",
                     required=True,
                     action='store',
                     help="Operating system to install on guest machine")
parser.add_argument("--ami_id",
                     required=False,
                     help="AMI ID for image base")
parser.add_argument("--instance_type",
                     required=False,
                     action='store',
                     help="Type of instance determines overall performance (e.g. t2.medium)")
parser.add_argument("--ssh_key_path",
                     required=False,
                     action='store',
                     default=os.environ['HOME']+'/.ssh',
                     help="SSH key path (e.g. ~/.ssh)")
parser.add_argument("--ssh_key_name",
                     required=True,
                     action='store',
                     help="SSH key name (e.g. mykey)")
args = parser.parse_args()
print(vars(args))
```

json example code:

```
{
  "variables": {
    "aws_access_key": "{{ env `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` }}",
    "aws_secret_key": "{{ env `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` }}",
    "magic_reference_date": "{{ isotime \"2006-01-02\" }}",
    "aws_region": "{{ env 'AWS_REGION' }}",
    "aws_ami_id": "ami-036affea69a1101c9",
    "aws_instance_type": "t2.medium",
    "image_version" : "0.1.0",
    "guest_os_type": "centos7",
    "home": "{{ env `HOME` }}"
  },
```

so, the user input for the `--region` as shown in the python script shoul get plugged into the value for `aws_region` in the json file.

I am aware of how to print the value of args. The full command that I am providing to the script is: `python packager.py --region us-west-2 --guest_os_type rhel7 --ssh_key_name test_key` and the printed results are `{'access_key': 'REDACTED', 'secret_key': 'REDACTED', 'region': 'us-west-2', 'guest_os_type': 'rhel7', 'ami_id': None, 'instance_type': None, 'ssh_key_path': '/Users/REDACTEDt/.ssh', 'ssh_key_name': 'test_key'}` .. what i need is to import thos values into the `packerfile.json` variables list.. preferably in a way that i can reuse it (so it musn't overwrite the file)

Note: I have also been experimenting with using python to export local environment variables then having the JSON file pick them up, but that doesn't really seem like a viable solution.

I think that the best solution might be to take all of these arguments and export them to its own JSON file called `variables.json` and import these variables from JSON (variables.json) to JSON (packerfile.json) as a seperate process. Still could use guidence here though :)

Comment: After `parse_args()`, `print(args)` to see what the parser has produced.  `print(vars(args))` will show the same thing as a dictionary.  `args,region` will be the value parsed as `region`.

Comment: so I am aware of how to print the value of args. The full command that I am providing to the script is: `python packager.py --region us-west-2 --guest_os_type rhel7 --ssh_key_name test_key` and the printed results are `{'access_key': 'REDACTED', 'secret_key': 'REDACTED', 'region': 'us-west-2', 'guest_os_type': 'rhel7', 'ami_id': None, 'instance_type': None, 'ssh_key_path': '/Users/REDACTEDt/.ssh', 'ssh_key_name': 'test_key'}` .. what i need is to import thos values into the `packerfile.json` variables list.. preferably in a way that i can reuse it (so it musn't overwrite the file)

Comment: This is really a `packer` issue, not an `argparse` one.  The `parser` gives you access, in your Python script, to a set of variables (or call them attributes).  You could collect those values in a JSON compatible dictionary, and use the standard `json` module to dump that as a string or file.  But whether that helps with `packer` I don't know.

Comment: What do you think about just treating packer as though I’m simply dealing with json... that is what I’m trying to do.. now I know that packer gives me the ability to have my variables located inside of a different json file... so I was thinking of just generating a json file with the py script into the current working directory and using it as the bar.json file.

Comment: If you are wondering about my use case... I’m trying to make it so that I can have a single script that will apply any value to a packer variable and ultimately all of our packer images will be powered via a single packer json file... thus we would only ever need to version a single json file rather than dozens of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was actually able to come up with a pretty simple solution.

```
    args = parser.parse_args()
    print(json.dumps(vars(args), indent=4))
    s.call("echo '%s' > variables.json && packer build -var-file=variables.json packerfile.json" % json_formatted, shell=True)
```

arguments are captured under the variable `args` and dumped to the output with `json.dump` while `vars` is making sure to also dump the arguments with their key values and I currently have to run my code with `>> vars.json` but I'll insert logic to have python handle that.

Note: s == subprocess in `s.call`

Answer (score 0):

You might use the `__dict__` attribute from the `SimpleNamespace` that is returned by the `ArgumentParser`. Like so:

```
import json
parsed = parser.parse_args()
with open('packerfile.json', 'w') as f:
  json.dump(f, parsed.__dict__)
```

If required, you could use `add_argument(dest='attrib_name')` to customise attribute names.

Comment: What is the function of `__dict__`? also, I edited my question to include the important bits of that json file... hopefully to provide a bit more clarity.

Comment: vars(foo) (as you found out in your updated solution) is pretty much similar to immediately using foo.__dict__. So I suppose your approach is cleaner, but mostly equivalent to mine :-)